# Why network change listener not works in my app?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I want to archive network change listener in my app. For example: When I start my app without ON Mobile Data and Wifi then it shows "Network unavailable!". After that when I ON Wifi or Mobile Data than that it automatically get data online and show on UI.

I have Main activity which already extends Fragment implements interface as well as base fragment too. 
I tried broadcastreceiver but it not works. when I run app without network it shows no internet connection two time. And after Wifi ON not update automatically but when I clicked Other Option in menu then UI shows. Please help me...

1- Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BaseFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    private Realm realm;
    private Results results;
    RecycleAdapter recyclerAdapter;
    BroadcastReceiver receiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder
                (MainActivity.this)
                .build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabletListener(Results result) {
        DetailFragment detailFragment = (DetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_detail);

        if (detailFragment != null) {
            detailFragment.updateTabletUI(result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Results currentMovie) {
        DetailFragment detailFragment = (DetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_detail);

        if (detailFragment == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class)
                    .putExtra("movie_Id", currentMovie.getId())
                    .putExtra("movie_Name", currentMovie.getTitle())
                    .putExtra("poster_Path", currentMovie.getPoster_path())
                    .putExtra("back_poster_Path", currentMovie.getBackdrop_path())
                    .putExtra("release_Date", currentMovie.getRelease_date())
                    .putExtra("users_Rating", currentMovie.getVote_average())
                    .putExtra("overview", currentMovie.getOverview());
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            detailFragment.updateTabletUI(currentMovie);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.favoriteList) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, FavoriteActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

2- Base Fragment class

```
public class BaseFragment extends android.app.Fragment implements RecycleAdapter.GetDataFromAdapter {

    @Bind(R.id.recyclerView)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private static final String STATE_MOVIES = "state_movies";
    private View rootView, noView;
    private DataManager dataManager;
    private RecycleAdapter recyclerAdapter;
    private MovieResponse movieResponse;
    private List<Results> resultsList;

    private Results results;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private int menuItemPosition;
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(STATE_MOVIES, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) resultsList);
        outState.putInt("menu_item", menuItemPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.most_Popular:
                if(item.isChecked()){
                }else{
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    menuItemPosition = item.getItemId();
                    makeService("POPULAR");
                    return true;
                }
            case R.id.high_rated:
                if(item.isChecked()){
                }else{
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    menuItemPosition = item.getItemId();
                    makeService("TOP");
                    return true;
                }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        // this will get called when the activity is re-created on device configuration change
        menu.findItem(menuItemPosition).setChecked(true);
    }



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_base, container, false);            

        ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
        resultsList=new ArrayList<Results>();
        configRecycleView();

        if (savedInstanceState==null){
            receiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                int status= NetworkStatus.getConnectivityStatus(context);
                if (status==0){
                }else{
                     makeService("POPULAR");
                }
                }
            };
            menuItemPosition = R.id.most_Popular;
        }else{
            resultsList=savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(STATE_MOVIES);
            menuItemPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("menu_item");
            recyclerAdapter.addMovieList(resultsList);
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    private void configRecycleView() {
        AutofitGridlayout layoutManager = new AutofitGridlayout(getActivity(), 200 );
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerAdapter = new RecycleAdapter(getActivity(), BaseFragment.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    }

    private void makeService(String query){
        dataManager = new DataManager();
        Call<MovieResponse> listCall;
        if (query=="TOP") {
            listCall= dataManager.getJSONData().getTopMovies();
        }else{
            listCall= dataManager.getJSONData().getPopMovies();
        }
        listCall.enqueue(new Callback<MovieResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MovieResponse> call, Response<MovieResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Results[] results = response.body().getResults();
                    resultsList = new ArrayList<Results>(Arrays.asList(results));
                    recyclerAdapter.addMovieList(resultsList);
                    Results firstResult=resultsList.get(0);
                    mListener.onTabletListener(firstResult);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MovieResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Snackbar.make(rootView, R.string.Network_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCurrentMovie(Results currentMovie) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(currentMovie);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onTabletListener(Results result);
        void onFragmentInteraction(Results result);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

3-  NetworkStatus class

```
public class NetworkStatus {

        public static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
        public static int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
        public static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;

        public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (null != activeNetwork) {
                if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                    return TYPE_WIFI;

                if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                    return TYPE_MOBILE;
            }
            return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
        }
}
```

4- manifest ---

```
<manifest package="com.santossingh.popularmovieapp"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.FavoriteActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_favorite"
            android:parentActivityName=".Activities.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".Activities.MainActivity"/>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.VideoActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_video"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.DetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
            android:parentActivityName=".Activities.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.santossingh.popularmovieapp.Activities.MainActivity"/>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.ReviewActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_review"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is it seems you have not set receiver for network in manifest file, so in Manifest file after all activity tags completed, inside application tag write down below code to register your receiver.

```
     <receiver android:name=".Activities.NetworkChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

 </application>
```

**Note that if you don't have receiver then check below and use it.**

```
     import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
     import android.content.Context;
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.widget.Toast;

     public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

       @Override
       public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) 
       {

         String status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context); 
         Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
   }
```

Comment: But how and where to call NetworkChangeReceiver class in BaseFragment class ?

Comment: You don't need to call it as now it is registered from Manifest file so, it will initialise as soon as app start and start to notify for internet connectivity.